# ubuntu 14.04 realtek rtl8812ae scans but can't connect

Tags: wireless, realtek

I've recently purchased the D-link DWA-582 PCI mini card (RTL8812AE) and happily installed on my mobo. The driver that comes with it supports only Windows. On my Ubuntu 14.04, it's however able to scan and show results, but when I tried to connect to any of the SSID, it just never reached out.

- tried both 2.4GHz and 5GHz,
- tried kernel 3.16,

but no luck so far. May I know what should I do?

[WiFi diagnosis logs](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10641287/)

SSID to connect: BoppStation or BoppStation_5G

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include the results.

Comment: @DavidFoerster i've tried to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure and paste the result here but it contains far more characters than allowed, any particular part that could be eliminated? thanks in advance

Comment: i've uploaded the wifi diagnosis here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/irg2plxsg0m7lw8/wifi_diag?dl=0

Comment: The `dmesg` output shows heaps of debug messages from the wireless driver module, that look like the sign of a bug. From what I can find, a [kernel update may help](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-sehen-aber-ich-kann-mich-nicht-verbinden/), but it [may also be related to the access point](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242621).

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [German forum thread](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-sehen-aber-ich-kann-mich-nicht-verbinden/) it may help to update the kernel to at least v3.14. Since Utopic's kernel is based on v3.16, you can simply install that (just the newer kernel, not all of Utopic)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

and reboot to the new kernel.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. tried this method but it didn't work out. guess will have to wait for the proprietary driver

Answer (score 1):

According to an other [thread](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/dlink-dwa-582/) of the same German forum, just try Ubuntu 16.04. 14.04 is just too old, even through the drivers are installed (but a staging version). I tested it on LIVE USB with the daily build and my DWA-582 works fine now.

Since the Linux kernel v4.4 included with Ubuntu 16.04 is also included in Ubuntu 14.04.5 it should be enough to run a full upgrade of Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If you only want to install the newer kernel (or make sure that it was actually installed during the full upgrade) run:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problems with my D-link DWA-582, but the other answers didn't work out for me.

I uninstalled the Ubuntu network-manager and installed wicd (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as I read somewhere some problems could be caused by the network manager. This fixed the connectivity problems to both 2.4 and 5GHz, but speeds were limited to about 2Mbps, this was on Ubuntu 16.10 .

Then I installed the latest driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new (build with make && sudo make install and insert in kernel with modprobe -v rtl8821ae, notice: rtl8821ae not rtl8812ae). This raised speeds to 40Mbps (on 5GHz), which is consistent with the speeds from the Windows driver.

Note: I also installed the new kernel 4.9 somewhere during this, so I'm not sure whether installing the drivers from the github repo is really necessary.